# Import seaborn produces SHIM warning

Tags: python, ubuntu, seaborn

If I try to import `seaborn` in my script I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/html.py:14: ShimWarning: 
The `IPython.html` package has been deprecated. You should import from 
`notebook` instead. `IPython.html.widgets` has moved to `ipywidgets`. 
"`IPython.html.widgets` has moved to `ipywidgets`.", ShimWarning)
```

I installed `seaborn` from `pip` at the last version `0.7.1` on Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.
Anyone has ideas?

`seaborn` is working but this warning is very annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue in the seaborn project explaining the reasons and solutions for this problem: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/874

Basically it says:

```
pip install ipywidgets
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not an `Error`, it's a `Warning`.

To avoid `Warnings` from showing up you can put before importing `seaborn`:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Warnings of all types won't show up anymore

Comment: As languitar's answer works to fix this depreciation warning, I think turning off warnings is not the optimal approach here.